# General reference for finite dimensional $*$-algebras over $\mathbb R$?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

What references are there for studying finite-dimensional $*$-algebras over the field $\mathbb R$ in their full generality? We assume these are associative and unital.

Note that:

- Not every algebra over $\mathbb R$ can be made into a $*$-algebra. The path algebra of the quiver $\bullet\rightarrow\bullet\leftarrow\bullet$ is a counterexample. In fact, the path algebras of most quivers provide counterexamples.
- Not every $*$-algebra is a $C^*$-algebra.
- Many finite-dimensional $\mathbb R$-algebras of practical interest can be made into $*$-algebras. For instance: commutative algebras, group algebras, Clifford algebras, and matrix algebras over any of the preceeding.

The study of these things seems rather non-trivial, so a reference would be appreciated.

Comment: The path algebras of quivers ARE very much of practical interest, though :-)

Comment: @M.G. Sure. I've edited the question.

Comment: Chapter 2 of "Schmüdgen, Konrad. An invitation to unbounded representations of*-algebras on Hilbert space. Cham: Springer, 2020." covers a lot of material on *-algebras over R, properties that do/do-not transfer through their complexification, etc.